# mongodb not updating all the documents

Tags: mongodb, updating

I have documents
`{name:"ajeetkumar",age:26}` and `{age:26,name:"ajeetkumar"}` stored in collection sample.

I want to update the age field and i use command `db.sample.update({name:"ajeetkumar"},{$set:{age:28}})`

It only updates the first document where name is the first field. Why? How to update all the records given a field. Is order of fields affecting the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {name:"ajeetkumar",age:26} and {age:26,name:"Ajeetkumar"}
>
> db.sample.update({name:"ajeetkumar"},{$set:{age:28}})

In the second document name is starting with uppercase A so you should use regex in this one. Plus you have to use multi option. This one will work well for you:

```
db.sample.update({name: /^ajeetkumar/i},{$set:{age:28}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry Maxim that was a typo mistake. Name was ajeetkumar. But I get ur answer and that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

by default it only updates one you have to set the multi option, [more info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

try this:

```
db.sample.update({name:"ajeetkumar"},{$set:{age:28}}, false, true)
```

Also the query is case sensitive so in your case it still would not update the second one.

> {name:"ajeetkumar",age:26} and {age:26,name:"Ajeetkumar"}

In the second document name is starting with uppercase A. Might want to look into [regex matching](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: If they were both capital A it would still only update one record. If that is the issue, then he could look into matching with regex.